# How to Send Same Data in Two Database Using Message Broker in Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, broker

I want to Send Same Data in Two Database Using Any Message Broker in Node Js
but i don`t understand how to send same data into two database please give proper solution.

**I am using MQTT Broker**
**Broker code**

```
var mosca = require('mosca');
var settings = { port: 1883}
var broker = new mosca.Server(settings)


var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'root@123',
      database: 'abc'
});

db.connect(() => { 
    console.log("db connect");
})

broker.on('ready', () => { 
    console.log("broker is ready");
})

broker.on('published', (packet) => { 
    message = packet.payload.toString()
    time = packet.payload.toString()
    add = packet.payload.toString()
    console.log(message);
    if (message.slice(0, 1) != '{' && message.slice(0, 4) != 'mqtt') {
        
        // var dbSet = 'insert into mqttjs set ?'
        var dbSet =`INSERT INTO mqttjs (message, time, add) VALUES ("a","b", "c")`;
        // var data = {
        //     message: message
       
            
        // }
        db.query(dbSet, (error, output) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);

            } else {
                console.log("data saved");
            }

        })
    }

})
```

**subcriber**
This is subscriber code

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.0.92')
client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('myTopic')
})
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
context = message.toString();
console.log(context)
})
```

**pulisher**
This is publisher code

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.0.92');
client.on('connect', function () {
setInterval(function() {
    client.publish('myTopic', 'Hello mqtt');

console.log('Message Sent');
}, 5000);
});
```